# run file from different directory

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, centos, sed

I have a directory `mainfolder` with a subdirectory `execution` which contains a `configure` script. I can switch to the `execution` directory and run `./configure` and it works fine. Now I'm trying to figure out how to run the `configure` script when I'm in `mainfolder`. I tried:

```
./configure /execution
```

and:

```
./configure execution
```

but neither worked. I also tried the same thing using the full path either starting from root directory or from user directory like this:

```
./configure /home/etc/user/mainfolder/execution
./configure user/mainfolder/execution
```

I always got the message:

> bash: ./configure: No such file or directory

Finally, I tried:

```
/home/etc/user/mainfolder/execution/configure 
. /home/etc/user/mainfolder/execution/configure
```

Both gave me the error:

> sed: can't read makefile.in: No such file or directory

How can I do this?

Comment: @Dchris , could you run `file /home/etc/user/mainfolder/execution/configure` and if its a script or ascii text do a `grep -A5 -B5 "sed" file /home/etc/user/mainfolder/execution/configure` and paste the result here ?  ..... it might be that the makefile.in which i think sed is supposed to make change/update to might be missing or the path might have been changed. This was we can confirm it.

Comment: @NSD Updated result in my question

Comment: @Dchris , sorry .... forgot to remove the 'file' from the grep

Comment: @Dchris ,thank you .. the sed command is substituting some values from/to the makefile.in descriptor file .... the makefile.in seems to be mentioned a bit below in the command than what has been reported back by the grep command ..... you would need to locate that makefile.in and change the path/location so that it is accessible in the /home/etc/user/mainfolder/execution/configure directory then it should work fine

Comment: @NSD makefile.in file is located in the same directory as configure file is

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9168/discussion-between-dchris-and-nsd)

Comment: this is not a issue of the configure file or the location then .... sed is not able to make the update's to your makefile.in .... the command is something of this nature `sed -e 's/src_pat1/replace_txt1/g' -e 's/src_pat2/replace_txt2/g' makefile.in`  which should work !! i dont understand why its not working .....

Comment: @NSD What does "sed -e 's/src_pat1/replace_txt1/g' -e 's/src_pat2/replace_txt2/g' makefile.in" does?

Comment: do a `man sed` .... you will get all the details there.

Answer (score 1):

First confirm that the configure script is present where you think it is. Second make sure that it's executable:

```
$ ls -l ./configure 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 saml saml 100 Jun  9 05:11 ./configure
```

If both of the checks are OK then you might want to try running `configure` by first changing directories to `/mainfolder/execution` and then running `configure` like this:

```
$ cd /mainfolder/execution
$ ../configure
```

You also might want to try it this way:

```
$ cd /mainfolder
$ ./configure execution
```

#### EDIT #1

According to comments left by OP, the following directory structure appears to be what he's describing:

```
$ tree -f
.
`-- /mainfolder
    `-- /mainfolder/execution
        `-- /mainfolder/execution/configure
```

Comment: $ ls -l ./configure command is ok when i run it in execution directory but when i run it in mainfolder directory i have the message "ls:cannot access"

Comment: ./configure execution didn't work

Comment: OK, so what you're telling us is that the `configure` script is present in the directory `/mainfolder/execution` and not in the dir. `/mainfolder`. This would explain why you can't run `configure` from the `/mainfolder`, it isn't located where you think it is.

Comment: Does my edit reflect what dir. structure you have? If this is correct, then you can't run `configure` the way you've been trying to.

Comment: what is tree -f?

Comment: A Unix command to list the directory structure. Almost all Unix commands (such as `tree` and `ls`) have what are called man pages. You can find out more about a command in your shell by typing `man ls` or `man tree`. Here's tree's man page: http://www.computerhope.com/unix/tree.htm. Incidentally don't try this with `configure`, this isn't a program, it's a script that's part of the software you're trying to install.

Answer (score 0):

In *nix `/` always is the root directory of the whole file system and `.` always refers to the current working directory.

Every path starting with `/` is an absolute path. Every path starting with `.` is a relative path.

Hence `/home/...` is probably correct, as this directory lives it the root directory, whereas `/excecution` is probably wrong as this directory does *not* live in the root directory, but somewhere under `/home/...`.

If you say `./configure`, you try to run the file `configure` living in the current working directory (`.`).

The error `No such file or directory`, well, just says that there is no file named `configure` in the current working directory.

You can use `pwd` to show, what the current working directory is. Use `ls` to show what files exist there. Use `cd` to change the current working directory.

To help you with your actual problem. You need to say what you were trying to do. Why do you want to run `configure`? What is it supposed to do? Why do you think you need to specify the execution directory?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that I have to run the file but don't change my current directory. So I tried this and worked:

```
cd execution/ && ./configure
```

Comment: I'm glad you were able to solve you issue but in the future, please try and ask your question correctly and give accurate information. I realize this might be difficult given your new to Linux, but your question and all these answers is of little value to the Unix & Linux site as a whole. As you refine your question through comments and your own research feel free to update and refine your question. At this point you've wasted a lot of peoples time and left a bit of a mess here now with this useless question. I don't mean this in a rude way at all, I'm just trying helping you to understand.

Comment: This doesn't do the job anyhow, does it?   You end up in the execution directory as your current working directory after doing this command.

Comment: The actual answer is here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/786376/how-do-i-run-a-program-with-a-different-working-directory-from-current-from-lin